# connecting asp with web-service [wsdl-nusoap]

Tags: php, asp.net, wsdl, nusoap

I Have a function that i want to use it in web-service ... for wsdl and nusoap
another users that connect to me with php havent any problem on nusoap  .but whos connect me with asp can add my web-service and see my 2 classes for example enqueue and get credit but cant work with this 2 method ... i didnt work with asp.....
here is my functions and my web-service how i change this files to whos work with asp can connect to me and where is the problem

here is my index.php

```
    <?php header('Content-Type: text/xml');

    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/gw.interface.php');


    $server = new SoapServer('gw.wsdl', array('uri' => 'uri:SMSServer','encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

    $server->setClass("gwi"); 
    $server->handle();
```

// i think here i must register my functions??

```
?>
```

and here is my functions in gw.interface.php

```
public static function getstatus(&$batchid, &$unique_id)
    {
        $uname = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        $pass  = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

        if(!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !db::exists('`users`', '`uname`="'.$uname.'" AND `upass`="'.$pass.'"'))
        {
            return array('state' => 'error', 'message' => 'Username or/and Password doesnt match.', 'errnum' => '102', 'cost' => '-1', 'msgid' => '-1');
        }

        $number = sms_send::number_info($uname, $from);

        db::update('`users`', '`sents`=`sents`+1', '`uname`="'.$uname.'"');

        $gate = SMSGate($number['gateway'], $number['gwuname'], $number['gwpass'], $number['company']);


        $sents = sms_send::get_sents($msg_id);

        if($sents[0]['state'] == 'working')
        {
            return array('state' => 'error', 'message' => 'Message is still in sending procces, try after the proccess is done.', 'errnum' => '107', 'rcpts' => array());
        }

        $sent_rcpts = sms_send::get_sent_rcpts($msg_id, $sents[0]['batchid']);

        return array('state' => 'done', 'message' => 'Each recieptor\'s state fetched successfully.', 'errnum' => '100', 'rcpts' => $sent_rcpts);

    }
```